# Python Thread Lock Fails?

Tags: python, multithreading, locking

I wrote a code to test Threading with lock.
What I want to see is that B is always right after A,
and no other letters come in between them
cause I am using lock for block 1 (A) and block 2 (B) in sub thread 1.

```
# IMPORT //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
import numpy as np
import threading


# GLOBAL VARIABLE /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
str = ""


GLOBAL CONSTANT /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
MAX_LEN = 70


SETTING /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
lock = threading.Lock()


def function_sub1(): 
    global str

    while True:
        with lock:
            # block 1
            str += 'A'
            print(f"sub 1 - block 1: {str}")
    
            # block 2
            str += 'B'
            print(f"sub 1 - block 2: {str}")
    
        # block 3
        str += 'C'
        print(f"sub 1 - block 3: {str}")
    
        if len(str) >= MAX_LEN:
            str = str[:MAX_LEN]
            break


def function_sub2(): 
    global str

    while True:
        # block 1
        str += 'D'
        print(f"sub 2 - block 1: {str}")


        # block 2
        str += 'E'
        print(f"sub 2 - block 2: {str}")


        # block 3
        str += 'F'
        print(f"sub 2 - block 3: {str}")
    
        if len(str) >= MAX_LEN:
            str = str[:MAX_LEN]
            break


RUN /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
sub_thread1 = threading.Thread(target=function_sub1) 
sub_thread2 = threading.Thread(target=function_sub2) 

sub_thread1.start() 
sub_thread2.start()


join /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
sub_thread1.join() sub_thread2.join()

print("fin:", str, "with len:", len(str))
```

Well, the reality is that it does not work as I expected.
Below is one of my run result.

`fin: ABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCADEFDEFBDCABCAEFDEFBCDABCABCABCAEFBDEFCABCA with len: 70`

You see, A and B are interrupted.
Why so?

Then, I tried applying lock to the other thread also, in case.

```
def function_sub1(): 
    global str

    while True:
        with lock:
            # block 1
            str += 'A'
            print(f"sub 1 - block 1: {str}")
    
            # block 2
            str += 'B'
            print(f"sub 1 - block 2: {str}")
    
        with lock:
            # block 3
            str += 'C'
            print(f"sub 1 - block 3: {str}")
    
        if len(str) >= MAX_LEN:
            str = str[:MAX_LEN]
            break


def function_sub2(): 
    global str

    while True:
        with lock:
            # block 1
            str += 'D'
            print(f"sub 2 - block 1: {str}")
    
        with lock:
            # block 2
            str += 'E'
            print(f"sub 2 - block 2: {str}")
    
        with lock:
            # block 3
            str += 'F'
            print(f"sub 2 - block 3: {str}")
    
        if len(str) >= MAX_LEN:
            str = str[:MAX_LEN]
            break
```

Now the result,

`fin: ABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCDEFDEFDEFABCDEFABCDEFDEFABCDEFDEFABCDEFD with len: 70`

I wouldn't know why but it seems to be working in this case.
However, it is not very random than I expected. I wanted something like

`fin: ABDEABCABF...`

you know?

Long question, but I tried to make the best exemplary code.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The code you're running is extremely fast. The repeated characters at the start are probably caused by the thread startup time, where the first thread can execute without any contention from the second thread until it is completely initialized. You're probably also running into the global interpreter lock, GIL (meaning only one thread can operate at a time-- not true parallelism) and that the threads in Python only obtain the GIL about every 100 bytecode executions or so (allowing many of these simple actions from one thread to complete before execution is switched).

Comment: Thank you for your detailed comments! It really does help me to understand.

Comment: Note that in your code, you have a single lock around adding both A and B.  So you'll always have AB together in your output.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand _"I wouldn't know why but it seems to be working in this case."_, but: a lock only makes sense if you use it in _multiple_ threads, in your first version it is meaningless because the 2. threads has no requirement to respect it.

Comment: You are misunderstanding the concept of [the synchronization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronization_(computer_science)#Thread_or_process_synchronization). In the first example code, the second thread does never call the ```lock.acquire()```, so any code in that thread can be executed while the first thread is holding the lock.

Comment: Frank Yellin: Yes, that's what I want AB together, but doesn't work.

Comment: Timus & relent95: Okay, thank you for your comments. So I guess I must apply locks to both of the threads.

Comment: @relent95: `with lock:` does the  `acquire()` and `release()`.  The code is correct.

Comment: @Frank Yellin, no, in the first example code, there's no ```with``` statement on the ```lock``` in the second thread.